# Adding 3 Polynomials via Linked lists

Tags: c++, object, linked-list, polynomials

I was trying to add 3 polynomials through linked lists and managed to create the following program in C++ which is working for some of the cases, but is not working for all of them.
The problem is, I am not able to figure out for which testcases the program is giving wrong output(as all cases are not visible on hackerrank).
Any corrections or help on sources of errors would be appreciated.

I basically took the 3 linked lists for input and added their coefficients corresponding to each power from 0 to 100 (limit for range of powers is 0 to 100) and put these in a new linked list (with head node head_node_final) and then output it.

Standard case for which I got correct ans:

Input:

```
2      //2 terms in 1st linked list
1 1    // 1*x  
2 10   // 10x^2
2      //2 terms in 2nd linked list
1 0    //1
10 2   // 10x^2
2      //2 terms in 3rd linked list
10 2   //10x^2
1 3    // 1x^3
```

OUTPUT:

```
(1,3)+(30,2)+(1,1)+(1,0)    // x^3+30x^2+x+1
```

CODE:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class node
{
public:
    int power;
    int coefficient;
    node *next;
};

int main()

{

int n1;
cin >> n1;

node *head_node1 = new node();

int inp_coefficient1;
cin >> inp_coefficient1;
head_node1->coefficient = inp_coefficient1;
int inp_power1;
cin >> inp_power1;
head_node1->power = inp_power1;
node *value = head_node1;

for (int i1 = 1; i1 <= n1; i1++)
{

    if (i1 != n1)
    {

        cin >> inp_coefficient1;
        cin >> inp_power1;
        node *value_new = new node();
        value_new->coefficient = inp_coefficient1;
        value_new->power = inp_power1;

        value->next = value_new;
        value = value->next;
    }
    else
    {
        value->next = NULL;
    }
}

int n2;
cin >> n2;

node *head_node2 = new node();

int inp_coefficient2;
cin >> inp_coefficient2;
head_node2->coefficient = inp_coefficient2;
int inp_power2;
cin >> inp_power2;
head_node2->power = inp_power2;
value = head_node2;

for (int i2 = 1; i2 <= n2; i2++)
{

    if (i2 != n2)
    {

        cin >> inp_coefficient2;
        cin >> inp_power2;
        node *value_new = new node();
        value_new->coefficient = inp_coefficient2;
        value_new->power = inp_power2;

        value->next = value_new;
        value = value->next;
    }
    else
    {
        value->next = NULL;
    }
}

int n3;
cin >> n3;

node *head_node3 = new node();

int inp_coefficient3;
cin >> inp_coefficient3;
head_node3->coefficient = inp_coefficient3;
int inp_power3;
cin >> inp_power3;
head_node3->power = inp_power3;
value = head_node3;

for (int i3 = 1; i3 <= n3; i3++)
{

    if (i3 != n3)
    {

        cin >> inp_coefficient3;
        cin >> inp_power3;
        node *value_new = new node();
        value_new->coefficient = inp_coefficient3;
        value_new->power = inp_power3;

        value->next = value_new;
        value = value->next;
    }
    else
    {
        value->next = NULL;
    }
}

node *head_node_final = new node();
node *value_final = head_node_final;

for (int power_counter = 100; power_counter >= 0; power_counter--)
{

    node *node_value1 = head_node1;
    while (node_value1 != NULL && node_value1->power != power_counter)
    {
        node_value1 = node_value1->next;
    }
    int node_1_return;
    if (node_value1 == NULL)
    {
        node_1_return = 0;
    }
    if (node_value1 != NULL)
    {
        node_1_return = node_value1->coefficient;
    }

    node *node_value2 = head_node2;
    while (node_value2 != NULL && node_value2->power != power_counter)
    {
        node_value2 = node_value2->next;
    }
    int node_2_return;
    if (node_value2 == NULL)
    {
        node_2_return = 0;
    }
    if (node_value2 != NULL)
    {
        node_2_return = node_value2->coefficient;
    }

    node *node_value3 = head_node3;
    while (node_value3 != NULL && node_value3->power != power_counter)
    {
        node_value3 = node_value3->next;
    }
    int node_3_return;
    if (node_value3 == NULL)
    {
        node_3_return = 0;
    }
    if (node_value3 != NULL)
    {
        node_3_return = node_value3->coefficient;
    }

    if ((node_1_return + node_2_return + node_3_return) != 0)
    {
        value_final->power = power_counter;
        value_final->coefficient = (node_1_return + node_2_return + node_3_return);
        value_final->next = new node();
        value_final = value_final->next;
    }
    if (power_counter == 0)
    {
        value_final = NULL;
    }
}

node *new_value_final = head_node_final;
while (new_value_final->next != NULL)
{
    cout << "(" << new_value_final->coefficient << "," << new_value_final->power << ")";
    if (new_value_final->next->next != NULL)
    {
        cout << "+";
    }
    new_value_final = new_value_final->next;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: why do you write your own linked list to add polynomials? Isnt a `vector` of coefficients much easier and less error prone?

Comment: if you think the problem requires a linked list you could use `std::list`, but for most stuff `std::vector` is superior

Comment: your code could benefit a lot from using functions. Instead of writing the same code 3 times to create 3 lists you could call the same function 3 times. Less repetition = less code = less errors

Comment: I cannot reproduce your example case: https://godbolt.org/z/1zTh8oYfK

Comment: Astonishingly, your program works. Just your input is wrong.You swapped in the 3rd input line the 2 and the 10. But, unfortunately, your program has nothing to do with a decent design . . .

Answer (score 0):

Your program produces the correct output for a given input.

But you have a typo in your input. In the third line you mixed up power and coefficent. See here:

```
2      //2 terms in 1st linked list
1 1    // 1*x  
2 10   // 10x^2 ************ Error: Should be 10 2 ************
2      //2 terms in 2nd linked list
1 0    //1
10 2   // 10x^2
2      //2 terms in 3rd linked list
10 2   //10x^2
1 3    // 1x^3
```

If you correct this, then your program will show

```
(1,3)+(30,2)+(1,1)+(1,0)
```

as well.

So, your program is basically working.

But the design is bad and the code quality low. Tons of repetitions. And everything completely fix. No flexibility. You should write many many comments, then you will see the problem for yourself.

The list implementation seems to be wrong. Usage of a list is also a wrong design for this problem.

But maybe the teacher told you to use a list. And maybe, even instead of using the existing `std::list`, reinvent the wheel and create your own list implementation.

I will not show a list implementation here. There are tons of implementations in the web. See for example [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60994/stl-list-implementation). There are many many more.

If we are talking about design, there is no need to store all given terms. There should be only one entry for a power and the coeeficients should be immediately added up. With such a design, you come immediately to a solution, were a `std::map` will be useful.

I created an example (you cannot use that, because it conatins no list) based on that approach with more advanced C++. You could take some ideas out of it.

The resulting code is rather compact in easy to use.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

// Any other number also possible, or event a number given by a user possible
constexpr unsigned int numberOfPolynomials = 3u;

// Here we store a polynomial, consisting of terms
struct Polynomial {

    // Powers and its coefficients sortet from large to small
    std::map<int,int,std::greater<int>> terms{};

    // Overwrite extractor operator. Read a complete polynomial from any stream
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Polynomial& p) {

        // First read the number of terms in the polynomial
        size_t numberOfTerms{}; is >> numberOfTerms;

        p.terms.clear(); // Delete old data
        // Read all terms. As given by input
        for (size_t index{}; index < numberOfTerms; ++index) {
            // Read coefficiend and power from stream
            int coefficient{}; int power{}; is >> coefficient >> power;

            // Add new coefficient for this power
            p.terms[power] += coefficient;
        }
        return is;
    }
    // Output all terms in thsi polynomial in the required format
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Polynomial& p) {
        bool printPlus{};
        for (const auto& [power, coefficent] : p.terms)
            std::cout << (std::exchange(printPlus, true) ? "+" : "") << '(' << coefficent << ',' << power << ')';
        return os;
    }
    // Add 2 polynomials. Just the coefficients for the relevant powers will be added
    Polynomial operator + (const Polynomial& other) const {
        Polynomial result{*this};
        for (const auto& [power, coefficient] : other.terms) result.terms[power] += coefficient;
        return result;
    }
};

// Some driver / test code
int main() {

    // Here we will store all polynomial that should be read. Anynumber ispossible.
    std::vector<Polynomial> polynomials(numberOfPolynomials);
   
    // Read polynomials from std::cin
    for (Polynomial& polynomial : polynomials) 
        std::cin >> polynomial;

    // Sum all up
    Polynomial sum = std::accumulate(polynomials.begin(), polynomials.end(), Polynomial{});

    // Show result of the addition
    std::cout << sum;

    return 0;
}
```